# Prevent background scrolling on open of lightbox

Tags: jquery, css, featherlight.js

I'm using [Featherlight](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#installation) as a lightbox. One problem I have is that went it opens, the background remains scrollable. A fix that most lightboxes need is adding a class to the body with `overflow:hidden;` on it.

**How can I do that on open of the lightbox, then remove the class on close?**

Comment: https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#configuration - this part of the documentation reveals all the callbacks on which you can bind for achieving this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily you don't wanna do overflow:hidden as this hides the scroll bars and can cause a repaint (which is slow)

Comment: Andrew! I see you have a real bee in your bonnet about the scroll bars being hidden and causing a repaint (since you've posted the same thing 3x, on the question here and two answers below:) Do you have a better solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the options on your plugin call by using of the `beforeOpen` and `afterClose` options like:

```
$.featherlight({
    beforeOpen: function() {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    },
    afterEnd: function() {
        document.body.style.overflow = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: This hides the scroll bars too and can cause a repaint

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps:

1) Add new CSS class as:

```
.bodyNoOverflow{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

2) Modify the Featherlight widget initialization configuration and modify the `beforeOpen` and `beforeClose` callback function as:

```
beforeOpen: function(event){

    $("body").addClass("bodyNoOverflow");
    //existing code if any
},

beforeClose: function(event){

    $("body").removeClass("bodyNoOverflow");
    //existing code if any
},
```

Comment: This hides the scroll bars too and can cause a repaint